# OpenCV default storage format

Tags: opencv

What is the default (Pixel) storage format used by OpenCV ?

I know it is BGR but is it BGR32 ? BGR16 ? 
Is it Packed or Planar ?

Can you suggest me a way to find it out?

Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] Context :  Actually I am trying to use OpenCV with another library called MIL (Matrox Imaging Library). I need to grab an Image with MIL and then convert it to an OpenCV Image. That is why I need to know the default pixel format, to configure MIL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image format is set by the flag when you create the image eg `CV_8UC3` means 8bit pixels, unsigned, 3colour channels.  In a colour image the pixel order is BGR, data is stored in row order.

The data isn't packed at the pixel level - it's 3bytes/pixel (BGRA is an option on some of the GPU calls).

Data may be packed at the line level, if the number of pixels in a row * the number of bytes/pixel isn't a multiple of 4 then the data is padded with zero to the next 32bit boundary. The call mat.ptr(n) returns a pointer to the start of the 'n' th row

Note that you can share memory with another comaptible image format by passing the data pointer from the MIL image to the ctor of the cv::Mat

Comment: Thanks !
By the way, I have already tried to pass the MIL Image buffer to the ctor of the Mat one but it didn't work :/

Comment: Care to be a bit more specific? It wasn't permitted or gave you the wrong result?

Comment: The reason I can't pass the Mil image to the ctor of the Mat is because the image I get from MIL has a type (MIL_ID) which is not recognized by OpenCV.

Comment: @Thibel that's just the handle to the image, there is a call (I forgot what) to get the actual MIL image data pointer

Comment: You probably mean MbufInquire(...) (or MbufGetColor(...)), I have already tried that but I get a strange image. Here is a [link](http://i.imgur.com/f56dIco.jpg) to the image.

Comment: That looks like the MIL data is planar, ie a red image followed by a green by a blue. You can either change the MIL to output packed, or create 3 cv::mat files for each plane and then combine them - either way you are goign to have to copy all the pixels

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you are managing the image: have you loaded it from a file with imread for example?
Have a look at imread [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html), with a colour jpeg for example you'll have a 3 channel format, 24 bits overall. Can you be more specific?

I do not know if it's useful, but I had a similar issue when converting an image from Android Bitmap (passed to OpenCV as a byte array RGBA8888) to OpenCV image (BGR888).
Here is how I've solved it.

```
cv::Mat orig_image1(orig_height, orig_width, CV_8UC4, image_data);   

int from_to[] = { 0, 2,  1, 1,  2, 0};    
cv::Mat image(orig_height, orig_width, CV_8UC3);   
cv::mixChannels(&orig_image1, 1, &image, 1, from_to, 3);
orig_image1.release();
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to use OpenCV with another library called MIL (Matrox Imaging Library). I need to grab an Image with MIL and then convert it to an OpenCV Image. That is why I need to know the default pixel format, to configure MIL.

Comment: OpenCV handles an image as a cv::Mat and it can have different depths as you can see here:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html
(search for "::depth")
It's true that BGR 888 format is commonly used, therefore I'd suggest you to convert the MIL image to that format.
I don't know now if MIL provides a stream of pixel bytes, but you may want to have a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114605/convert-a-byte-arry-to-opencv-image-in-c
In case you need to swap some channels, have a look at cv::mixChannels function as well.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try what you've suggested.