# Need to load image from database c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am newbie in OpenCV. I need to write a C++ program that loads the tiff image stored in the database. So I read the image as `char` buffer and I'm not sure how to create `Mat` object from that buffer.

Comment: is that buffer a tiff image ( like on disk, with headers and such ) ? or pixels ?

Comment: It is image file as such uploaded to the database

Comment: Content of char buffer is? And format (RGBRGB...RGB)?

Comment: It is a image file which is uploaded to database as binary data. The C++ program need to read the binary data from the database

Comment: Then you need to read the data first from the binary data. And then assign them to `Mat`'s content.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode

Comment: I found imdecode function which takes InputArray as argument and not sure how to pass the binary data. Which function should be used

Comment: vector<uchar> bytes; // read them from db  imdecode(bytes,-1); // -1: read unchanged, don't force to bgr or such

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a byte arry to OpenCV image in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114605/convert-a-byte-arry-to-opencv-image-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You need:

1. read the binary data into a `std::vector`, and then
2. feed that into `imdecode()`.

   ```
   std::vector<char> buffer(data,data+len); 
   Mat img = imdecode(buffer,-1); // use the data as is
   ```